# Trigger click event not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add `onclick` event to an image so when I click on the image it will trigger the file open dialog. But it doesn't work in IE10.

```js
$("#button").on("click",function(){
  $("#upload").trigger("click");
});
```

```css
#upload{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="button" src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />

<input id="upload" type="file" >
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot a window.onload

Comment: *"But it don't work on ie 10"* - Does it work in other browsers? Do you get errors in the browser's console? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: What exactly does not work: click or trigger?

Comment: In other browsers it work but on ie 10 when i click to image in dont do anything and no error in browser's console

Comment: can you try with `opacity:0.1`, input may not work because it's invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tested this in the newest FF, Opera, Chrome, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11. Its working everywhere.

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" />
<img id="button" src="http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});

$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    $('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
});
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type=file] {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/CSvjw/1549/)

Answer (score -1):

[This should answer your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730666/post-immediately-after-select-a-file)